# как создавать deployments вместе с pod через kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, изучаю kubernetes по книге "Kubernetes для DevOps" и наткнулся на такой момент, согласно книге при создании pod объекта, нативно должно создаваться Развёртывание - Deployment. Вопрос в чём - должно лили это самое развёртывание нативно создаваться?

Answer (score 0):

Вы некорректно поняли весь принцип работы кубернетес.

В кубернетес POD это минимальная неразделимая сущность которой вы непосредственно управляете.

POD'ы управляются сущностью ReplicaSet - которая следит за тем чтобы поды работали и при удалении восстанавливает их.

ReplicaSet в свою очередь управляется сущностью Deployment. Который следит за состоянием этих RS и отвечает за их обновление и замену.

Таким образом вы сначала создаёте Deployment с описанием того что вам нужно, а только потом сам Deployment создаёт уже ReplicaSet, который, в свою очередь, создаёт уже нужные POD'ы.